# How do I break a string into groups of letters with a loop in Java?

Tags: java, string, whitespace, breakpoints

I have to write a method which breaks a string into groups. The user should give the amount of letters per group and the function should return a string that consists of the input string broken into groups. For instance, function(“HELLOYOU”, 2) would return “HE LL OY OU”.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please show us your effort? What should be done if there is an amount of letters that cannot be divided, like `function("Hello", 2)`?

Comment: What about [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.split()` to break the string into an array of individual letters, and then combine pairs of letters, or larger groups, etc.

Here is some example code:

```java
String[] splitInParts(String input, int size) {
    String[] letters = input.split("");
    String[] output = new String[letters / size];

    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            output[i] = output[i] + letters[size * i + j];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

There is a lot of boilerplate code missing, for example, checking that loop parameters are in range, checking strings are not null, etc. However this is a rough idea of how you could go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the characters of input String to a new String and put whitespaces on every step that equals to "size":

```
String function(String input, int parts) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int partCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        partCounter++;
        result.append(input.charAt(i));
        if (partCounter == parts){
            result.append(" ");
            partCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code that takes in a `String` instance and aN `int` defining the number of characters to split based on. And then use the [`String` instances `split` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

```
public static String[] split(String input, int len){
    // To prevent any NullPointerException being thrown
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    // Split the input string based on a regex pattern
    return input.split(String.format("(?<=\\G.{%1$d})", len));
}
```

The Regular Expression that is being used here is `(?<=\\G.{%1$d})` which based on `len` being `2` would become `(?<=\\G.{2})`. So this means it would split every 2 characters. So the output for a string of `HELLOWORLD` would be `HE`, `LL`, `OW`, `OR`, `LD` .

If you wanted to join those into one `String` separated by a space you could using the [`StringUtils#join` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.String-).

```
String joinedString = StringUtils.join(split, StringUtils.SPACE);
```

Which would produce `"HE LL OW OR LD"`.

So an all in one method would be:

```
public static String separateNthCharacter(String input, int len) {
    // To prevent any NullPointerException being thrown
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty()) {
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }

    String[] split = input.split(String.format("(?<=\\G.{%1$d})", len));
    return StringUtils.join(split, StringUtils.SPACE);
}
```